# Connecting to ruby tcpserver from delphi using indy

Tags: ruby, delphi, apple-push-notifications, client, tcpserver

I got the following example (by: Matt S) running in cmd elevated mode: [How do you test the Push Notification feedback service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284908/how-do-you-test-the-push-notification-feedback-service)

I can connect to this ruby server by using "telnet localhost 2196" and it'll start sending data to the telnet client just fine.

However, if I then try to put this to use in delphi, using indy:

```
    TcpClient := TIdTcpClient.Create(nil);
    TcpClient.Host := 'localhost';
    TcpClient.Port := 2196;
    TcpClient.Connect;
```

I get the following error: Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused as soon as "Connect" is called. It appears as though the tcp server could not be found.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The error means the server is not listening on `127.0.0.1`. The server could be listening on other local IPs without listening on `127.0.0.1`.

`localhost` does not necessarily refer to just `127.0.0.1`.  Lookup queries via `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()` can resolve `localhost` to actual local IPs, which `telnet` would then try to connect to until one succeeds.

But Indy currently treats `localhost` as `127.0.0.1` only, without trying to resolve it dynamically:

```
function TIdStack.ResolveHost(const AHost: string;
  const AIPVersion: TIdIPVersion = ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  case AIPVersion of
    Id_IPv4: begin
        // Sometimes 95 forgets who localhost is
        if TextIsSame(AHost, 'LOCALHOST') then begin    {Do not Localize}
          Result := '127.0.0.1';    {Do not Localize}
        end else if IsIP(AHost) then begin
          Result := AHost;
        end else begin
          Result := HostByName(AHost, Id_IPv4);
        end;
      end;
    Id_IPv6: begin
        if TextIsSame(AHost, 'LOCALHOST') then begin    {Do not Localize}
          Result := '::1';    {Do not Localize}
        end else begin
          Result := IdGlobal.MakeCanonicalIPv6Address(AHost);
          if Result = '' then begin
            Result := HostByName(AHost, Id_IPv6);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    else begin
      IPVersionUnsupported;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Even if Indy tried to resolve `localhost` as a hostname, it does not attempt to connect to all reported IPs. That is a [TODO item](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/164) on Indy's issue list.

My advice would be to resolve `localhost` manually with `getaddrinfo()`, then use a loop to run through the reported IPs, resetting the `TIdTCPClient.Host` (and possibly `TIdTCPClient.IPVersion`) and calling `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` for each one, until one succeeds or the loop ends.

Comment: Using 127.0.0.1 gives me the same issue unfortunately. Also, trying 127.0.0.1 on telnet - does not connect it properly either - while telnet on localhost does work.

Comment: I know, that is the point I was trying to make.  When the server is not actively listening on `127.0.0.1`, clients cannot connect to `127.0.0.1`.  Binding the server to `0.0.0.0` does not guarantee a binding to `127.0.0.1`. Clients have to connect using an IP that the server is actually listening on. Indy treats `localhost` as `127.0.0.1` only, it won't try to resolve `localhost` to other local IPs.

Comment: Nice - never knew. ill test this soon. An alternative and perhaps more straightforward solution would be to explicitly tell Ruby to start on 127.0.0.1 -> server = TCPServer.open("127.0.0.1", 2196)

Comment: You could, but just know that doing so, the server will only be accessible to clients on the same machine, not to outside clients on the same LAN, or other networks.  If you need that, leave the server the way it was, and just have local clients on the same machine connect to a correct IP, which you can get from `netstat`.